# how to connect a certain website and a visual basic project using two computers

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I have website project and a visual basic project but these two projects are on the different computer. the website project is on my first computer and the visual basic project is on the other computer. So my question is how can I connect this two projects using this two computers? Is there any source code for connecting this two projects? I'm using PHP and MySQL for my website project and the language that I use for the visual basic project in c#.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

VB code can do HTTP requests just fine. There are libs for other protocols too.
Use them. If you need VB to not only retrieve HTML, then expose some API on PHP side, and call it in VB.

Other direction is not possible. Still if VB is associated with some MS Office app, you may be able to use native windows XCOM capabilities. Look for PHP to XCOM bridge/lib, if that's what you need.